# Why Apache IoTDB reported error when setting the encoding method of TXT data type to RLE?

Tags: encode, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I set the encoding method of TXT data type to RLE, and seems like this causes the Apache IoTDB database to report error and the datanodes to hang up. I think I may have got the corresponding encoding method wrong, so does anyone know what may cause this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding method of `TEXT` data type can be `PLAIN`, so try to set the `default_text_encoding` parameter to `PLAIN` to see if the Apache IoTDB database can be executed normally.